# Where to download visual studio express 2005?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to find download link for VS express 2005 but no luck.

I need this version, not 2008.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why won't 2008 do what you need?

Comment: 2008 has 'multi-targeting' (I believe this is in the express version) so you could target the 2.0 framework if that is your reasoning.

Comment: My guess is he's trying to join an existing project where everyone else is using 2005.

Comment: @šljaker Could you go ahead and accept the second answer (with the most upvotes?  It would be more helpful for those of us (like me) who come after.

Comment: You can download ISO file from https://offlineinstallersofts.com/download-visual-studio-2005-iso-offline-installer-windows.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only way (in 2021) is through the my.visualstudio.com site.  You must have a Microsoft Account in order to download it.

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%20express%202005%20

It is listed as deprecated though.  There is no support for it anymore.

Comment: Haha, seems MS just trolled devs for a while, here is the link http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/3/a/83aad8f9-38ba-4503-b3cd-ba28c360c27b/ENU/vcsetup.exe

Comment: Both those links are dead now.

Comment: @Barnaba updated with latest link.

Answer (score 133):

For somebody like me who lands onto this page from Google ages after this question had been posted, you can find VS2005 here: http://apdubey.blogspot.com/2009/04/microsoft-visual-studio-2005-express.html

EDIT: In case that blog dies, here are the links from the blog.

> All the bellow files are more them 400MB.
>
> Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition
>   449,848 KB
>   [.IMG File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=54763) | [.ISO File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57037)
>
> Visual Basic 2005 Express Edition
>   445,282 KB
>   [.IMG File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=54764) | [.ISO File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57033)
>
> Visual C# 2005 Express Edition
>   445,282 KB
>   [.IMG File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=54765) | [.ISO File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57035)
>
> Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition
>   474,686 KB
>   [.IMG File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=54766) | [.ISO File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57034)
>
> <s>Visual J# 2005 Express Edition</s>
>   <s>448,702 KB</s>
>   [<s>.IMG File</s>](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=54767) | [<s>.ISO File</s>](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57036)

Comment: credit goes to the author of the blog :)

Comment: all express vs 2005 offline images, c#, c++, etc. Upvoting

Comment: As of March, 2017, this link still works. Saved me when I had to rebuild some legacy software.

Comment: can anyone confirm installing this side by side with VS 2017/2019 affect anything?

Comment: Still working in 2020 Thanks !

Comment: As of May 2020, these links are still working

Comment: Still good in 2023 (the .isos you get are the same that can be found in the my.visualstudio.com website below)

Answer (score 12):

You can still get it, from microsoft servers, see my answer on this question:
[Where is Visual Studio 2005 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780741/where-is-visual-studio-2005-express-at/780822#780822)

Comment: Note, its Visual C# only

Answer (score 6):

> As of late April 2009, Microsoft has
>   discontinued all previous versions of
>   Visual Studio Express, including 2005.
>   It is no longer possible to obtain
>   these previous versions from the
>   Microsoft website.

From [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express)

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/3/a/83aad8f9-38ba-4503-b3cd-ba28c360c27b/ENU/vcsetup.exe

Answer (score 4):

Small tip for you.  Microsoft frequently has 'launch parties' or 'launch events' in which they frequently distribute licensed, not for resale copies, of that product.  I've gotten the last two versions of VS (2005 and 2008) by attending my local .NET user group chapter during those days.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but I don't think I have ever seen them give out the Express Edition. Full copies certainly, Express, never.